# Why doesn't Firefox do a preflight request with fetch when Authorization header is set, but Chrome does?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, firefox, preflight

TL;DR: Chrome sends a pre-flight with fetch when Authorization header is set; Firefox does not. I want to understand why there's a difference.

I have a simple webpage that I'm using to test Bearer authorization with `fetch()`:

```
<html><body>
Testing.
<script>
  // Insecure page
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/hello2')
  .then(response => {
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(content => {
    document.querySelector('#hello2').innerHTML = content
  });
  // Secure page
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/secure/hello1',
    { headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer super_secure_token_1'} }
  )
  .then(response => {
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(content => {
    document.querySelector('#hello1').innerHTML = content
  });
</script>
<div id='hello1'>HELLO1</div>
<div id='hello2'>HELLO2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(The page above is served on `http://localhost:8081`: so a different origin, if that makes any difference).

My understanding is that when the `Authorization` header is set, the browser should do a preflight request using the OPTIONS method because it is no longer a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests). However, Firefox does not do this; Chrome does (and Safari, Edge too).

*(Ironically, this causes the site to work properly under Firefox, because I haven't worked out the CORS issues yet --- for some reason the CORS headers are missing from the OPTIONS response --- but that's a separate question)*

Here are my server logs showing this.

#### Logs for Firefox

As you can see, Firefox simply sends the GET request, and gets a response. No problem.

(Request and response for `/hello2` removed)

```
{
   "timestamp":"2023-05-10 08:09:19.916516",
   "level":"DEBUG",
   "name":"Application",
   "pid":68526,
   "msg":"",
   "context":{
      "request_id":"956abd1c-ef01-11ed-8485-ae6922d47386",
      "request":{
         "method":"GET",
         "path":"/secure/hello1",
         "parameters_query":{
            
         },
         "parameters_path":[
            
         ],
         "headers":{
            "sec-fetch-site":"same-site",
            "connection":"keep-alive",
            "dnt":"1",
            "origin":"http://localhost:8081",
            "authorization":"Bearer super_secure_token_1",
            "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
            "referer":"http://localhost:8081/",
            "accept-encoding":[
               "gzip",
               "deflate",
               "br"
            ],
            "host":"localhost:8080",
            "accept-language":[
               "en-GB",
               "en;q=0.5"
            ],
            "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
            "accept":"*/*",
            "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
         }
      }
   }
}{
   "timestamp":"2023-05-10 08:09:19.974010",
   "level":"DEBUG",
   "name":"Application",
   "pid":68526,
   "msg":"",
   "context":{
      "request_id":"956abd1c-ef01-11ed-8485-ae6922d47386",
      "response":{
         "status_code":200,
         "headers":{
            "Server":"RestRserve/1.2.1; Rserve/1.8.11",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

#### Logs for Chrome

Chrome, however, send an OPTIONS preflight, then gets a 401 response.

(Request and response for `/hello2` removed)

```
{
   "timestamp":"2023-05-10 08:14:44.556680",
   "level":"DEBUG",
   "name":"Application",
   "pid":68695,
   "msg":"",
   "context":{
      "request_id":"56eac068-ef02-11ed-aed3-ae6922d47386",
      "request":{
         "method":"OPTIONS",
         "path":"/secure/hello1",
         "parameters_query":{
            
         },
         "parameters_path":[
            
         ],
         "headers":{
            "accept-language":[
               "en-GB",
               "en-US;q=0.9",
               "en;q=0.8"
            ],
            "referer":"http://localhost:8081/",
            "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
            "accept":"*/*",
            "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
            "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            "connection":"keep-alive",
            "sec-fetch-site":"same-site",
            "access-control-request-method":"GET",
            "host":"localhost:8080",
            "origin":"http://localhost:8081",
            "access-control-request-headers":"authorization",
            "accept-encoding":[
               "gzip",
               "deflate",
               "br"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}{
   "timestamp":"2023-05-10 08:14:44.581290",
   "level":"DEBUG",
   "name":"Application",
   "pid":68695,
   "msg":"",
   "context":{
      "request_id":"56eac068-ef02-11ed-aed3-ae6922d47386",
      "response":{
         "status_code":401,
         "headers":{
            "WWW-Authenticate":"Basic"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: "CORS headers are missing from the OPTIONS request" do you mean from the OPTIONS response? because I can see the CORS request headers in the chrome output

Comment: I don't see you specifying `credentials` in your request options, so the default `same-origin` should apply - meaning, the browser should _not_ send your `authorization` header. (Maybe there was a recent change, and Firefox and Chrome differ these days on what the default value should be?)